# SSH refusing connection - "sshd: unrecognized service"

Tags: networking, ssh, 12.10, sshd

I am having an issue with SSH.

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.7 port 22: Connection refused
```

I get the above error whenever I try to connect my desktop with another desktop using SSH, but I'm able to ping the other desktop successfully.

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.7 port 22: Connection refused
```

When I attempt to restart sshd, it outputs the following error

```
sshd: unrecognized service
```

I can connect to remote server using SSH, but I'm not able to connect within the local network. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide the command line you are using, or the application. Also add the **Ubuntu** version. *Are these two desktops on the same LAN (local network)?*

Comment: How are you trying to start the ssh daemon? You should be using `sudo service ssh start`. If that doesn't work, could you post the output of `ls -l /etc/init/ssh.conf` ?

Comment: @david6, if they weren't on the same LAN, then the connection would just fail or be blackhole'd.  He's getting a refused connection which means that a computer saw the request and sent back a refusal.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 12.10, where I need to ssh to another computer within the same local network. But, I'm able to connect to a remote server in another network. Please help me...

Comment: Confirm if you are using a firewall. Is **SSH server** installed on each target host?

Comment: maybe your SSH daemon is not listening to external connections. try connecting locally using `ssh localhost` from the machine.

Answer (score 13):

Try un-installing and then installing openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server
```

This worked for me. If you still can not connect, try

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

and let us know what the output is.

Comment: I am having the same problem and the output of `sudo ufw status verbose` is `status: inactive` , so I enabled it but the error persists, this is the new output `Status: active
Logging: off
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
`

Answer (score 6):

First make sure that ssh service running on 192.168.1.7 or not..it is possible that system doesn't have an SSH daemon, so you need to install ssh on that system.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If it's already installed, run `sudo service ssh restart`, then comment here with the output of this command from both the systems.

Comment: When I restart the ssh it stops first and starts with a PID no.

Comment: Thank you this seems to be precisely the case for me...  openssh-server had to be installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

In my installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop edition from the Ubuntu website, openssh-server is not installed by default. BIG FAT THUMBS DOWN Canonical!!!!! The installation is relatively easy and has been mentioned already by other answers above:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Comment: Many people don't use ssh. I think it's alright to not include the server by default on the desktop edition.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your router either, can accept ssh or has it enabled somewhere in the settings. Sometimes something this simple can be overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto `vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Change the Authentication "PermitRootLogin" to "yes"

   Eg:

   ```
   Authentication:

   PermitRootLogin yes
   ```
3. `service sshd restart`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have SSH server installed:

```
dpkg -l openssh-server
```

If not, install it:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y ssh
```

Now check if your 22 port is in use:

```
netstat -atn | grep :22
```